# method that is both callable as class method and mixed in as a class method?

Tags: ruby, mixins

In Ruby, is it possible to define a method that can be called directly as a class method and is also able to be mixed in as a class method? That is, without using `self.included` or `self.extended` to create an equivalent class or instance method.

Neither of these approaches works:

```
module A
  def foo(s)
    puts s
  end
end

class One
  extend A
end

One.foo("one")
#A.foo("a")

module B
  def self.foo(s)
    puts s
  end
end

class Two
  include B
end

#Two.foo("two")
B.foo("b")
```

There seems to be some confusion as to what is being asked.  Here's a less abstract scenario.  A is a mixin that can be used directly.  B is a mixin, intended to be used independently of A, that "wraps" one of A's methods.

```
module A
  # #foo has to be defined in order to be mixed in via `extend`.
  # Being mixed in via `include` has the same issue but inverted.
  def foo(s) A.foo(s) end 
  def self.foo(s) puts "A: " + s end
end

module B
  def foo(s) A.foo("B: " + s) end
end

class One; extend A end

class Two; extend B end

One.foo("one")
Two.foo("two")
```

In order for this to work, both `A#foo` and `A::foo` have to be separately defined.  Existing facilities such as `Module#module_function` don't work under this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand, what is the issue here?

Comment: what is the problem with `extend`ing, again?

Comment: Your question and your code are misaligned. Right now `One.foo` will `puts` the variable `s` to the screen because you used extend which makes these class methods. In the second example you have not done anything to `class Two` because `B.foo` is scoped explicitly to `B` due to the `self`. Please clearly define your intended result

Comment: The desire result is that either `One.foo("one"); A.foo("a")` or `Two.foo("two"); B.foo("b")` work with the same method.

Comment: @JoshuaHoblitt if that's all you want create a module with a method foo and the simply use extend in the classes.

Comment: @engineersmnky The question was about having both class and instance callable versions of a method without defining both versions of the method.  How are your proposing to use `extend` that is different than in my non-working example?

Comment: @JoshuaHoblitt what is wrong with your new example? You can reference any top level constant from inside a module or Class as you are doing now. This works fine for me and returns 'One.foo("one") #=> A: one` and `Two.foo("two") #=> A: B: two` what was you expectation?

Comment: @JoshuaHoblitt I have updated my answer with another solution that may work for you.

Comment: @engineersmnky The question starts with "is it possible".  The answer could certainly be "No". :)

Comment: How about instance method just delegating to the class method? Not the same exact method, but effect is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try not to be definitive but to my knowledge the answer to your question is No. If you would like to mixin both instance and class methods then the standard methodology would be something like:

```
module A 
  def self.included(base)
    #this will extend the class you included A in
    #using A::ClassMethods definition
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
  #these methods will be added as class_methods to any class
  #that includes A
  module ClassMethods
    def foo(s)
      "You fooed the class with #{s}"
    end
  end
  #this will be added as an instance method as it would be in a standard include
  def bar(s)
    "You barred an instance with #{s}"
  end
end

class Mixed
  include A
end
Mixed.foo("Hello")
#=> "You fooed the class with Hello"
Mixed.new.bar("Hello")
#=> "You barred an instance with Hello"
```

I hope this answers your question as it was a bit unclear what your intentions were. Since you question does not seem to require instance methods you could also do this

```
module A 
  def foo(s)
    "called foo with #{s}"
  end
end
module B
  include A
  alias_method :a_foo, :foo
  def foo(s)
    "B called foo from A #{a_foo(s)}"
  end
end
class Mixed
  extend B
end

Mixed.foo("Mixed")
#=>"B called foo from A called foo with Mixed"
```

**One more update**

This is a strange pattern but it will work for your use case I believe

```
module A
  def foo(s)
    "fooed with #{s}"
  end
  def bar(s)
    "barred with #{s}"
  end
end

module B
  include A
  included_modules.each do |mod|
    (mod.instance_methods - Object.methods).each do |meth|
      alias_method "#{mod.name.downcase}_#{meth}", meth
    end
  end
end

class Mixed
  extend B
end

Mixed.methods - Object.methods 
#=> [:a_foo, :a_bar, :foo, :bar]
```

This way you can overwrite methods in `B` and call the `A` version but if you don't overwrite it will still call the `A` version.

You could also monkey patch the `Module` class if you'd like to make this functionality universal

```
class Module
  def include_with_namespace(*mods)
    #Module#include runs in reverse so to maintain consistency my patch does as well
    mods.reverse.each do |mod|
      include mod
      (mod.instance_methods - Object.methods).each do |meth|
        alias_method "#{mod.name.downcase}_#{meth}", meth
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then this will work

```
module C
  def foo(s)
    "C's foo with #{s}"
  end
  def see_me
    "You can see C"
  end 
end

module B;include_with_namespace A, C; end

class Mixed;extend B;end

Mixed.methods - Object.methods
#=> [:a_foo, :a_bar, :c_foo,:c_see_me, :foo, :bar, :see_me]
Mixed.foo("name")
#=> "fooed with name"
Mixed.c_foo("name")
#=> "C's foo with name"
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP was asking, but it's still worthwhile to show the customary way that class methods are included.

Comment: The question did specifically say without `self.included`... and not having to separately define the class and instance version of the method.

Comment: @JoshuaHoblitt yes but just because you ask a question does not mean you will get the response you want. This is how it is conventionally done in ruby.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution -- importing the instance method to be wrapped and aliasing it to preserve it.  Before I mark this as the accepted solution, why is `A` extending `self`?

Comment: @JoshuaHoblitt sorry I copied some code I had written while trying to solved this for you the `extend self` was a relic and not needed I have removed it completely.

Comment: @JoshuaHoblitt the reason i had `extend self` in there is that it is an efficient way to create a singleton which is what I was messing around with. `extend self` basically makes all of the instance methods class methods instead. It acts as short hand for `module A; class << self; def foo(s);#...;end;end;end`

Comment: @JoshuaHoblitt added one more pattern that might work for you.

Comment: The last example does essentially what I was looking for a built-in facility to provide.

Comment: However, I don't yet understand why `Module#module_function` is incompatible with the mixin methods.

Comment: @JoshuaHoblitt since you wanted this to be more universal I have added a monkey patch to `Module` that allows for the preserved name spacing. Please note in the example `Mixed.foo` will be `A.foo` because `Module#include` runs in reverse so my code does as well. Hope this helps and thanks for the fun project.

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
module A
  def foo(s)
    puts s
  end
end

class One
  singleton_class.include A
end

One.foo('hi')
  #=> 'hi'
```

but that's pretty close to [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-extend).

If:

```
module A
  def self.foo(s)
    puts s
  end
end
```

and you want to know if `A` can be referenced from a class `C` to make `foo` a class method of `C`, my understanding is that the answer is "no". I say "my understanding" because it is not something that can be proved; it was, as I understand, a design decision Matz made.

Comment: What difference would this have over `class One; extend A; end`?

Comment: @engineersmnky, none. It's probably how `extend` is implemented.

Comment: You could technically access `A.foo` through `One` if you don't mind a top_level warning :). Something like `One::A.foo` will work but produces `warning: toplevel constant A referenced by One::A`. you could also use something like `One.included_modules.find{|mod| mod == A}.foo("hi)` but that seems overly complex to just reference `A`.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I never thought about that, but it still doesn't include the class method. btw, whenever I see your name I think it's too bad you didn't get in on Clinton's [vowel drop](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/humor/clinton-deploys-vowels.html).

Comment: Hahaha my name is actually inspired by the Grateful Dead's song Monkey and the Engineer  and you are right it will never act as a class method doing it this way

Comment: This question has gotten out of control but if you are interested in my updates take a look.